# What are your favorite small handy utility programs (tools) helping you programming ?

Tags: utilities

And how they help you improve your programming ? Could they be integrated in IDE and if yes how ?

Edit: Thanks to [altCognito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38971/altcognito) There has been almost duplicate question before named: 
[What's in Your Utility Tookit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173328/whats-in-your-utility-toolkit)**.  "Allmost" since the listings there do not provide short explanations of what exactly each tool does
Edit: If this question stays and you want to add a new tool please please according tool's popularity

A simple tool listing

- [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for powerful text searching
- [ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/cms/showpage.php?cid=97) - it remembers the last n amount of entries in the ClipBoard. The shortcut combination Ctrl + Shift + Z , 2 gives you the second last copied text ( or object ) from the Windows Clipboard. Never heard of it being somehow used within VS , neither have I missed such an integration ...
- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) - for killing unwanted processes ( VS Team Services Help for example ) + vast grip of overall system info on Windows
- [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html) - use this often for writing or tweaking graphics (Visual Studio provides little in the way of decent graphics editing). Paint.NET is great for making transparent PNGs or GIFs - click the "Magic wand" tool to select the area you want to make transparent, and then hit Delete

You could find a broader [list](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2009/05/cool-programs-for-windows-most-of-which_24.html) on my blog ...

Comment: duplicate of god knows how many other questions

Comment: @Neil: Just one is good enough, as long as you can link it. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173328/whats-in-your-utility-toolkit

Comment: Whoops, that's the one linked in the question. Now I *have* to find another, or else I just closed a legitimate question.

Comment: I can't find one, so I'll cast the first reopen vote.

Comment: Well I asked about SMALL utility programs : 
The answers from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173328/whats-in-your-utility-toolkit questions included: 
Visual Studio ( very small one ; ) , Power Shell etc. + they did not have proper explanation of the functions of the small program ...
Well the community runs the StackOverflow ...

Answer (score 2):

Expresso: excellent free and stable tool for regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

- VisualSVN plugin for Visual Studio - SVN integration within VS.Net
- myGeneration - for code generation
- CCTray - for getting real-time updates on CruiseControl builds
- SQL 2005 query analyzer, ofcourse for queries
- jquery add-in for Visual Studio for jquery methods intellisense
- Resharper - for error highlight on the fly & several other features
- watIn test recorder - for recording test scripts
- nUnit - for executing unit test cases
- InBuilt code snippets
- XML to Schema - specifically for VB.net in VS 2008

Answer (score 1):

Paint.NET and Notepad++.

Paint.NET - use this often for writing or tweaking graphics (Visual Studio provides little in the way of decent graphics editing). Paint.NET is great for making transparent PNGs or GIFs - click the "Magic wand" tool to select the area you want to make transparent, and then hit Delete.

NotePad++ for the ability to right-click any file of any size and view its raw contents - bypassing the default viewer for the file.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) will let me edit live on the server is an absolute godsend.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourites is a teensy perl script I wrote that drops formatting from text so I can cut (from email or word doc) and paste the plain text sans foppery.

And here it is;

```
# Ridiculously simple, but very useful.
use Win32::Clipboard;
my $text = Win32::Clipboard::GetText() or exit;
Win32::Clipboard($text) if $text;
```

Comment: Funny I did sometimes this one:
 package removeEnters ; 
 use strict ; 
 use warnings ; 
 use Win32::Clipboard ; 
 main(); #action !!!
 sub main 
 {
 local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
 my $text = Win32::Clipboard::Get(); #get the text from the clipboard

 #added the logic to remove the enters only in paragraphs
  $text =~s/\r\n([a-z])/ $1/g ; #remove the enters out of it
 $text=~s/(—End—|ATTENTION)/\n\n$1\n/gi ;
 print "the text is \n" ; 
 print "$text" ; 
 Win32::Clipboard::Set("$text");
 }
 1; 
 __END__

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/).  Mainly because it's automatic syncorisation allows me to easily view and alter all my notes in the office, at home or anywhere else that I have a web connection.

Answer (score 1):

- [debugview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) : for catching debug messages.
- [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) : excellent notepad replacement.
- [regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) : regular expressions editor and tester.

Answer (score 0):

[Refactoring Plugin for Eclipse](http://willcodejavaforfood.com/vu.html) that I am working on. Hopefully it will allow you to easily break up large classes suffering from too many methods/fields into smaller ones. Theory is that methods using similar fields belong together according to the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Sidebar for those sticky notes. good for quick copy and pasting code.

Answer (score 0):

- [Visual Assit X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) - This has a lot of small things that make editing source in Visual Studio better.  The install intergrates it seemlessly with the IDE.
- [IncrediBuild](http://xoreax.com/) - This will split your C/C++ compile over several machines and or processors.  It's a great way to utilize those old machines laying around, and multiple processors.  The install intergrates it seemlessly with the IDE.
- [Includes](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/samples/article.php/c1471/) - Shows all the header files a given file includes. I intergrate it by adding it to the external tools list in the IDE.
- [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) - When you fail to delete or rename a file or directory because it is locked this program automagically pops up a window showing what programs have it locked.  I don't intergrate this with the IDE.
- [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) - Compare files or folders.  I've replaced Visual Source Safe's  default compare program with Beyond Compare.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug and Web Development Toolbar (both for Firefox)-- no web developer should be without them.

Firebug lets you examine the structure of a document and edit the HTML/CSS on the fly.  It also lets you see the JavaScript involved.

Web Development Toolbar lets you disable CSS and the cache.  It lets you reset cookies.

Answer (score 0):

[Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/): As its domain name implies, Ack is better than grep. Mind-numbingly better than grep. So much better than grep that makes the original grep look brain-damaged.

I couldn't live without Ack.

Answer (score 0):

- [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn) -- task focused interface for Eclipse
- [Foglyn](http://www.foglyn.com/) -- for accessing FogBugz cases from Eclipse/Mylyn (shameless plug)
- [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) -- HTTP debugger, essential tool
- [CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html) -- Clipboard history
- [Faststone Screen Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) -- for making great screenshots
- Paint.NET -- for editing screenshots or icons

Answer (score 0):

2nd for [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). Inexpensive, powerful and available for Linux.